# How to see if changes from a branch are already done in another one?

Tags: git, branch, git-log

I would like to tell if all my code changes on BranchA are already applied on BranchB, regardless of whether the commit ids are the same or whether BranchB has  tons of extra changes

Is that possible?

Example:

```
 Branch A :  Commit 111... -> Add line 23
             Commit 222... -> Add line 24
 Branch B:   Commit 333... -> Add line 23
             Commit 444... -> Add line 24
             Commit 555... -> Remove line 24
             Commit 666... -> Add line 25
             Commit 777... -> Add line 26
What I basically would like to know is whether the two changes from Branch A are already applied by other commits on Branch B.
In this case, the output I would like to see is:

  - Add line 24

Why? Because this is the only change from Branch A not matching latest state of Branch B. I want to discard extra staff exclusive in Branch B (commits 666 and 777). I also want to consider latest state of Branch B, so even Branch B added at some point line 24, the latest state is removed, so that is the only differing change in regards to Branch A
```

When using compares and diffs I usually see all extra staff from Branch B which I am not interested as I only want to know differences in the context of Branch A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do :

```
git branch --contains BranchA
```

to list all branches which have all BranchA's commits. If you find your BranchB in the list, you're good.

And in case of many branches, pipe to grep :

```
git branch --contains BranchA | grep BranchB
```

---

***Edit after comments :***

If you have to detect changes regardless of the commits they belong to, for example when you rebased or cherry-picked some work, as [kostix suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53817698/how-to-see-if-changes-from-a-branch-are-already-done-in-another-one/53818182#comment94485852_53818182), you can do :

```
git log --cherry BranchB..BranchA
```

But then again, while the *detection* of changes will happen at code level, regardless of commit hashes, the output itself will be given as commits by default. To see the actual code changes within these commits, you can use the `-p` option, and probably store it in a file :

```
git log -p --cherry BranchB..BranchA > output.txt
```

Comment: But this is at commit level. I like to do it at code level. Is that possible?

Comment: @Whimusical, yes, see `git log --cherry`

Comment: The output is still showing commits and no code lines in my local attempt.

Comment: @RomainValeri I put a clearer example in the description

Comment: @Whimusical You're right, I had overlooked the output type/format, I've edited the answer. Hope it suits what you want.

Answer (score 3):

If you merge all your changes, this could be done with `git log BranchB..BranchA` (i.e. "give me all commits that are in A and not in B"). If this returns nothing, all A changes are applied.

There is not way to check this if you use rebase or implement changes in completely different way, because your changes could have been later altered or completely overwritten. You can try to grep some relevant lines or build the software and see if it has features you wanted, but there is no universal way.